# EF Core. How to extract (left) joined table as collection?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I need help for extract joined table as a collection in context linq-syntax expression.

```
public class Computer
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Component
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public int ComputerId { get; set; } //FK
   public Computer Computer { get; set; } //HasOne(Computer).WithMany().HasFK(ComputerId)
}
```

Computer no have backrefs to Components

Need to select computers with related components via Linq-syntax.

```
(from computer in db.Computers
join component in db.Components on computer.Id equals component.ComputerId into components //|  JOINED
from component in components.DefaultIfEmpty()                                              //|  TABLE
select new ComputerFullData
{
   Computer = computer,
   Components = components // <-- collection
})
........other code
```

This linq does not work and generate NullRefException
[image: NullRefException]

But, if *Computer* have *ICollection*< Component > **backref** property, than i would could extract collection of components via call Include(x => x.Components) which in fact is revert-JOIN like in my example. In this case, I could have problematic access to the collection of components.

How can I achieve the same through Linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works beautifully for me in EF Core:

```
public class Computer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Component
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ComputerId { get; set; }
    public Computer Computer { get; set; }
}

public class Db : DbContext
{
    public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
        = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());

    public DbSet<Component> Components { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Computer> Computers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
            .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb; Database=demo;Integrated Security=True");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new Db())
        {
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();

            db.Components.Add(
                new Component
                {
                    Computer = new Computer
                    {
                        Name = "Fred"
                    },
                    Name = "Fred component"
                });

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var db = new Db())
        {
            var computersWithComponents =
                (from c in db.Computers
                 select new
                 {
                     Computer = c,
                     Components = (from cp in db.Components
                                   where cp.ComputerId == c.Id
                                   select cp).ToList()
                 }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a lot like what you might write in SQL. I was pleased to find that referencing the context (`db`) in a sub-query like this is acceptable to the EF query provider, and the generated SQL is similar to what I might write by hand:

```sql
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [c0].[Id], [c0].[ComputerId], [c0].[Name]
       FROM [Computers] AS [c]
       LEFT JOIN [Components] AS [c0] ON [c].[Id] = [c0].[ComputerId]
       ORDER BY [c].[Id], [c0].[Id]
```

Out of interest—and I know this is not a direct answer to your question—why did you reject having the navigation property for `Components` on your model? I often find with EF that it's helpful to just do what works rather than try excessively hard to get exactly the model I would prefer. (If I have very specific requirements for the shape of the objects I need, I might have two class hierarchies - an EF database model which is idiomatic to EF, and my preferred model, with methods to translate between the two.) Anyway, in this case it's not too hard to get what you want, so that would likely be overkill here.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I used EF Core 3 in my example. In fact, the problem was not in the request itself, but in what happened next. Next, AutoMapper was used, which was not configured correctly. Having stopped using it, I noticed that the request is being built and executed correctly.